# Will tensorflow merge request/response between parameter server and worker and how is network IO done?

Tags: tensorflow

I am not familiar with tensorflow distributed runtime and graph schedule. Now we have say 30 groups of sparse features, all those features need to do embedding_lookup. I have two questions about communication between ps and worker.

1. Is it more efficient if we merge those 30 groups to one groups and lookup parameters using one single embedding_lookup call? If we keep them as 30 separate groups and invoke 30 calls, will tensorflow runtime detect it and send tensors to ps and receive tensors from ps by batch?
2. My understanding is worker will wait for parameter responses if worker has no more work to do. So how to drive tensorflow do as much work as possible instead of waiting for network IO since regularly we use one python loop to drive graph running? It's true we could start as many worker processors or threads as possible, but is there any better solution? for example is there any way to make tensorflow read data automatically and run next batch when they are waiting?